# Can't seem to save object into database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

This is my ActiveRecord:

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      t.datetime :due
      t.integer :priority
      t.text :tag

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to create an object inside `rails console` and save it, but it keeps returning false

```
irb(main):008:0> t =Task.new(title:"First task", body:"body of first task", due:"2020-12-29", priority:2, tag:"tag of first task")
=> #<Task id: nil, title: "First task", body: "body of first task", tag: "tag of first task", due: nil, priority: 2, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):018:0> t.save
=> false
```

I checked multiple sites to ensure my syntax is right, but I still can't save this object

My Task Model

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :container

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
  validates :priority, presence: true
  validates :due, presence: true
  validates :tag, presence: true

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an issue like that it is very easy to debug by outputting the errors on that instance. So when you get returned `false` when calling `save` then just `t.errors.full_messages` or call `f.valid?` and then `t.errors.full_messages`.

In your `new` parameter list you are missing a `container_id`. It is not obvious from the documentation but adding `belongs_to :container` internally adds a validation for the presence of that association (unless you pass the option: `optional: true`).

Furthermore – as others already pointed out – your database is missing a column to store the `container_id` that is used to store the association created by `belongs_to :container`.

So to solve your issue, you must do two things:

1. Define the `Container` model, its database table, and setup the `belongs_to` association correctly.
2. Pass an existing `container_id` to `Task.new`.

Comment: I removed Container field from my model, I forgot to remove the association

Comment: So the problem was because I did not remove the old assocation

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the hint*

Before saving the object (t.save in your example), run validations and check errors (t.valid? and then t.errors), so then you'll see all the errors. Sometimes it's useful to use in console, but also useful when you want to render the errors in controller (or wherever)

*As for the possible answer*

Please check the "belong_to :container". When you create the object with belong_to, you must pass the param (in your case it might be "container" as the ActiveRecord object, or just "container_id" with id of the Container object).
It seems, that you didn't add "belong_to" to migrations (it adds via "add_reference"), that's why you don't have it in the request. And that's possible reason why you can't create new object.